# Parsing XML node values with ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following XML:

```
<part>
 <part_id>151</part_id>
 <part_name>BBa_B0034</part_name>
 <part_short_name>B0034</part_short_name>
 <part_short_desc>RBS (Elowitz 1999) -- defines RBS efficiency</part_short_desc>
 <part_type>RBS</part_type>
 <release_status>Released HQ 2013</release_status>
 <sample_status>In stock</sample_status>
 <part_results>Works</part_results>
 <part_nickname/>
 <part_rating>1</part_rating>
 <part_url>http://parts.igem.org/Part:BBa_B0034</part_url>
 <part_entered>2003-01-31</part_entered>
```

And I want to extract some of the values.

For example I want to ouput the the `BBa_B0034` from `<part_name>`.

How would I do this using ElementTree?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the [documentation for `ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)?  Try to work with examples and write code and then post what you got here when things don't work the way you expect.

Comment: Duplicates :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786476/parsing-xml-in-python-using-elementtree-example?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need correct xml for parser correct. For reference using [Xml.etree Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example).

See example:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.fromstring('<part> <part_id>151</part_id> <part_name>BBa_B0034</part_name>     <part_short_name>B0034</part_short_name> <part_short_desc>RBS (Elowitz 1999) -- defines RBSefficiency</part_short_desc> <part_type>RBS</part_type> <release_status>Released HQ 2013</release_status> <sample_status>In stock</sample_status> <part_results>Works</part_results> <part_nickname/> <part_rating>1</part_rating> <part_url>http://parts.igem.org/Part:BBa_B0034</part_url> <part_entered>2003-01-31</part_entered></part>')
>>> tree.findall('./part_name')[0].text
'BBa_B0034'
```

Comment: Thanks for this but when I try and use that I get 'list index out of range' - I am parsing an xml from the web, as opposed to using 'fromstring'.

Comment: Check your xml text. From not same diferent from file. Both is stream.